# c# take snapshot from desktop

Tags: c#, .net

i'm making a application in c# for take snapshot from desktop ..so i can't understand correctly copyfromscreen method it's Graphics.CopyFromScreen Method (Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Size) according to msdn document. there are 5 parameters let's name them a1,a2,a3,a4,a5
a1,a2 image stating x,y. it's ok but a3,a4, called destination x and y and a5 is size ..i can't understand that i think i need only a1 a2 and a5 because there is start position and the size then all requirement is complete for draw a rectangle .in my application i set start position to form position and form is full transparent ..all i need is take a desktop snap shot inside the form .i make a msgbox for detect image size when i change a5 parameter(size) to different value a constant size appear in msgbox ..i don't know why it's 1023 768 and same to my desktop size .. important::::i want to take snapshot inside form visible desktop area so i need start point to set form start point and size a5 to form size but it's not work 
i want more about this method  it can't understand msdn document ..this is my c# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Bitmap screen=null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           // this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //  this.BackColor = Color.Red;
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.White;
        }
        public void snap()
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
            Bitmap screen1 = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
         Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(screen1))
            {
               Size a = new Size(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);
                Size reg = new Size(this.Width,this.Height);
                Size def = new Size(500, 800); 

                g.CopyFromScreen(this.Left, this.Top, int.Parse(textBox1.Text), 100, def);

            }
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

            pictureBox1.Image = screen1;

            screen1.Save("C:\\Users\\Madhawa\\Desktop\\java\\source\\Teboscreen_source_code\\"+random()+"screen.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            int sHeight = screen1.Height;
            int swidth = screen1.Width;
            MessageBox.Show("width:= " + swidth + "  height:= " + sHeight);

           // screen.Save("c:\\button.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.TransparencyKey = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            snap();
        }
        public static String random()
        { 
            ///////create different name for save image//////
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int ran1 = rnd.Next(1, 10000);
            int ran2 = rnd.Next(10000, 20000);
            int ran3 = rnd.Next(20000, 50000);
            //////////////////////////////////////////////
           // string time=  string.Format("{0_HH_mm_ss tt}", DateTime.Now);
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
            DateTime dateTime1 = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
            string date= dateTime.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy");
            string date1 = dateTime.ToString("HH_mm_ss");

            //////////////////////////////////////////////

            string myString = ran1 + "" + ran2 + "" + ran3 + "t" + date1 + "" + date;
            //string m = "";
            return myString;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You might edit your question to include question marks. Also, describe what your desired outcome is.

Comment: i want to take screenshot underneath of my form and want to know what is destinationx@y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your questions the key is this line:

```
Bitmap screen1 = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
```

This creates an bitmap image that is the same size as your primary Desktop, which I gather is the 1023x768.

The Graphics object allows you to draw onto that bitmap, but the underlying bitmap remains 1023x768.

If you are interested in ending up with only a 500x800 image you should change that to:

```
Bitmap screen1 = new Bitmap(500,800);
```

As for the drawing onto the Bitmap is concerned, here is a link to the msdn documentation [Graphics.copyFromScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw1kt6f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The parameters are

```
public void CopyFromScreen(
    int sourceX,
    int sourceY,
    int destinationX,
    int destinationY,
    Size blockRegionSize
)
```

It seems like you are trying to take a screenshot of just what is exactly underneath your form, correct me if I misunderstood your code.

So you want:

```
sourceX = this.left (assuming you are are calling from the form)
sourceY = this.top (assuming you are calling from the form)
destinationX = 0
destinationY = 0
blockRegionSize = new Size(500, 800)
```

edit: The sourceXY says where to get the screenshot from, in this case starting at the top left of the form. The destinationXY says where to paste the screenshot to, on the bitmap. Since we want the bitmap (the end result of the screenshot) to be just the 500x800 image, without a blank border above it or to the left, we want to draw starting at the top left corner of the bitmap...position (0,0).

I'm going to play around a little with setting the form transparent while taking a screenshot, in the past I have had trouble with setting the transparent key to Color.White, although colors like rgb(255,255,254) would go transparent correctly.

---

Regarding the transparency, I found a couple things that work, and a few that didn't.

Things that work:

First approach, just hide the whole form before taking the screenshot, and then show it again afterwards. Has the advantage that you don't need to also change the colors of all the buttons and labels on the form individually.

You may need to Thread.sleep(100) or manually call Form1.Invalidate() or something else just after hiding and before taking the screenshot, to give the screen time to hide the form completely.

```
Form1.hide(); 
snap();
Form1.show();
```

Second approach, change the opacity of the form. Similary to the first approach.

```
Form1.Opacity = 0;
snap();
Form1.Opacity = 100;
```

Using the transparencyKey on the form was much more difficult, and looked like this for me.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.Orange;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Hide();
        Form myForm = button1.FindForm();
        myForm.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        myForm.Hide();
        myForm.Show();
        myForm.Invalidate();

        Thread.Sleep(2000); //The form disappears for 2 seconds. 

        myForm.BackColor = Color.Black;
        myForm.Hide();
        myForm.Show();
        button1.Show();
        myForm.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, without hiding and reshowing the form, it wouldn't appear to redraw the background, So even though the background color would get set to Orange, you would still see the black background.

This could be due to some timing thing where the operating system made a pixel transparent, looked at what was under it, but still saw the old color of that pixel, and so drew that color instead. But that is just speculation.

Comment: yes yes you are exactly correct and i want to know why destination x and destination y equal to 0;

Comment: yes i also did hiding form and i recognize it takes some millisecond to hiding .but i want to see the screen capture region that's why i try to use transparent window..